# Cakephp Foreign key id not set properly

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

The reference id within 1..n or n..m database tables is not set automatic.
See my below example. I thought that client_id within subtables is set automatically everywhere, but in my case it is 0 in some cases.

**To be concreate: Users.client_id is set as supposed to client.id but the Contacts.client_id is always 0**

### DB

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `service_paid` date DEFAULT NULL,      
  `service_contract_accepted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `role` char(50) DEFAULT 'user',
   `token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `token_expires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `activation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_categories_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_indicator` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `company_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salutation` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `street_number` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(99) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `letter_salutation` text,
  `phonenumber_business` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobilenumber_business` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phonenumber_private` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobilenumber_private` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faxnumber_business` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faxnumber_private` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sepa_glid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vat_number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taxident_number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_office` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `important_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `important_day_text` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `important_day_resubmissin` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `important_day_reminder` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### VIEW

Within following clients/register VIEW - i have created this form

```
<fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->create($client) ?>

<h2 id="content"><?= __('Firmendaten') ?></h2>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.company_indicator',   ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => '1']); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.company_name',        ['type' => 'text',     'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Firmenname')]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.surname',             ['type' => 'text',     'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Vorname')]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.name',                ['type' => 'text',     'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Nachname')]); ?>

  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.street',              ['type' => 'text',     'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Straße'),               'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.street_number',       ['type' => 'text',     'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Nr.'),                  'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.postal_code',         ['type' => 'text',     'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('PLZ'),                  'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.city',                ['type' => 'text',     'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Stadt'),                'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.country',             ['type' => 'text',     'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Land'),                 'required' => true]); ?>

<h2 id="content"><?= __('Anwenderdaten') ?></h2>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.email',                       ['type' => 'email',    'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Email'),                'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.confirm_email',               ['type' => 'email',    'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Email wiederholen'),    'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.password',                    ['type' => 'password', 'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Passwort'),             'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('users.0.confirm_password',            ['type' => 'password', 'label'=> false, 'placeholder' => __('Passwort wiederholen'), 'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->input('service_contract_accepted',           ['type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => __('AGB'), 'default' => 0, 'hiddenField' => false, 'required' => true]); ?>
  <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</fieldset>
```

### CONTROLLER

This is processed within the ClientsController.php

```
public function register()
{
    $client = $this->Clients->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Users', 'Users.Contacts' ]]);

        if ($this->Clients->save($client)) {

            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Contracts', 'action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            debug($client);

            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('client'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['client']);
}
```

### Model

I have baked them all ... here we go

```
class ClientsTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('clients');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('AccountAllocationsTodefine', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('AccountingPeriodDetails', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('AccountingPeriods', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Accounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('AccountsFrameworks', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('AllocationValuesTodefine', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('BankAccounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('ContactCategories', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Contacts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Contracts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Counter', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('CounterTypes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('CounterValues', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('DataProperties', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('DataPropertyValues', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('DebitPosition', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Employees', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('EnergyCertificates', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Fees', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Files', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Floors', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('GlobalSettingsHeaders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Heatings', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Objects', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Owners', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Postings', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('RentPrices', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('ServiceProviders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('SettingsHeaders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('SettingsValues', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('TemplateAccounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('TemplateAllocationFormulas', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Templates', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('TenantDeposits', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Tenants', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Units', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    ]);
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->boolean('active')
        ->requirePresence('active', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('active');

    $validator
        ->date('service_paid')
        ->allowEmpty('service_paid');

    $validator
        ->boolean('service_contract_accepted')
        ->requirePresence('service_contract_accepted', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('service_contract_accepted');

    return $validator;
}
}


class UsersTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('username');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Clients', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Contacts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Employees', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('email')
        ->add('email', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('password');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('role');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('token');

    $validator
        ->dateTime('token_expires')
        ->allowEmpty('token_expires');

    $validator
        ->dateTime('activation_date')
        ->allowEmpty('activation_date');

    $validator
        ->boolean('active')
        ->allowEmpty('active');

    return $validator;
}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['client_id'], 'Clients'));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['contact_id'], 'Contacts'));

    return $rules;
}
}



class ContactCategoriesTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('contact_categories');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Clients', [
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('SettingsValues', [
        'foreignKey' => 'settings_value_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->boolean('active')
        ->requirePresence('active', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('active');

    return $validator;
}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['client_id'], 'Clients'));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['settings_value_id'], 'SettingsValues'));

    return $rules;
}
}
```

### QUESTION

Everything works fine except Contacts.client_id within DB is always set to 0.
I thought that cakephp handles the reference ids itself and sets them automatically.

How should i extend my code to get this client_id set automatically?

client_id is really in all of my tables and i need it set everywhere automatically.

Thanks 
Bülent

Comment: What you are seeing is (currently) the expected behavior. Why do you duplicate the client ID in both the `users` and the `contacts` table in the first place? Are contacts really ment to be able to exist without users? Given the hard link between users and contacts via their auto incrementing primary key, that is begging for problems.

Comment: If you did not put any value to that column which is not null and datatype integer it will automatically be null, change that to allow null

Comment: The client_id is somehow my MANDANT for the whole application. I have this client_id within each table and can choose directly from each table only the valid data for the current client. I want to be sure that none of the data is seen by someone else to whome the data does not belong to. Is there a documentation about this behavior? If i understand it right, the second level isn't set. `$this->Form->input('**users.0.contact.street**',...
 $this->Form->input('users.0.contact.street_number', ...`

Comment: Hi NDM, i do not understand this behavior. I have this code within Contacts `$rules->add($rules->existsIn(['client_id'], 'Clients'));`why is it not really checked? There is no 0 ID within client table so why is it inserted in the table without any exception?

Comment: It probably depends on where and how exactly the `0` is being generated. In order for the rule to test a value, it must be set in beforehand (of course), and the property must be marked as dirty. I'd suggest you add some breakpoints in the rule and check when and with what kind of data it is being invoked, and where it bails out. All I can do from here is guessing.

Comment: As far as automatic foreign key insertion goes, no, I don't think there's explicit docs on that. The current behavior however is, that FKs are only inserted when saving direct (first level) associations, doing it via users makes it an indirect (2nd level) association.

Answer (score 0):

And you are missing auto increment, just add AUTO_INCREMENT after primary key:

```
  CREATE TABLE clients
  (
     id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     // other as you did
  )
```

And also try replacing this line:

```
$client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, 
$this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Users', 'Users.Contacts' ]]);
```

by

```
$client = $this->Clients->patchEntity($client, 
$this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Users', 'Contacts' ]]); //
```

Comment: Did not change anything! Same issue as before. **Users.client_id is set but the Contacts.client_id is 0**

Comment: Hi Khadka, if i replace Users.Contacts to Contacts i get this exception - **Record not found in table "contacts" with primary key [NULL]** but this one should be autoincrement...

Comment: did you try to insert new record..after making changes?